# Opening grb2 files re-visited

Tags: matlab, grib

I have downloaded and installed [NCTOOLBOX](https://github.com/nctoolbox/nctoolbox) into MATLAB (2013a) to read netcdf and grb files.  As a test, I copied a netcdf, grb and grb2 file to a directory on my computer.  This is placed within my script as:

```
pathnc = 'c:\test\era40_moda_200205.nc'
pathgrb = 'c:\test\era40_moda_200205.grb'
pathgrb2 = 'c:\test\multi_1.at_4m.dp.200607.grb2'
```

I used the following code to read the *.nc file:

```
nc = ncdataset(pathnc);
nc.variables
```

The code works great....with no error messages..and all variables listed..on netcdf files...... however, when I run it for the grb files using:

```
nc = ncdataset(pathgrb);
nc.variables
```

I get this very long list of errors:

```
2014-03-05 08:40:15,744 [main] WARN  ucar.nc2.grib.grib2.Grib2Index  - Grib2Index bad size = -1 for c:/test/multi_1.at_4m.dp.200607.grb2 index = c:\test\multi_1.at_4m.dp.200607.grb2.gbx9

Warning: Escape sequence '\m' is not valid. See 'help
sprintf' for valid escape sequences. 
> In ncdataset>ncdataset.ncdataset at 89
  In GRIB_and_NC_Reader_Prog at 14 
Error using ncdataset (line 91)
Failed to open c:   est

Error in GRIB_and_NC_Reader_Prog (line 14)
nc = ncdataset(pathgrb2);

Caused by:
    Error using ncdataset (line 75)
    Java exception occurred:
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:
    alwaysUseFieldBuilders...............etc, etc....ad nauseum...............
```

In case it was just a bad file, I tried the code on a different grb file and got the same results.  Yes I have read the previous posts on reading grb with NCTOOLBOX...but still 'dead in the water.' I would greatly appreciate any insight to get my script reading grb and grb2 files.

Comment: Did you resolve this? If you can post a link to a sample Grib that's causing this error, I'll take a look at it for you. (I'm an author on nctoolbox)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar java error: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:alwaysUseFieldBuilders. I tried running the same code in R2014a and it worked.

Comment: This rather should in the comments section.